# How to handle value overloading exception in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

For example, -

```
short a;
cin>>a;
cout<<a;
```

---

Now, what if I insert a value bigger than 32,767? The program is going to crash. So I know how to handle exceptions, but something correct has to happen to throw an exception for the incoming wrong event. Like in a calculator, for a divide by zero exception, you will write-
`try {if (divider = 0){then do stuff}}`. But in my above example, there is no correct event and directly the wrong even takes place. What I mean by that is, in my calculator example, the program can detect that the divider is 0 and a wrong event is about to happen, but in my example I can't do something like this- `try{if(a>32767) {do stuff}}`, here my program can't detect the incoming wrong event as that wrong even takes place immediately, that is, the program can't detect that the value I have entered is more than it can take, because it anyways can't check my value as it bigger than its max value limit. So how can I prevent this kind of a exception?

Comment: You should only be using exceptions here if the data is never going to be user direct human input. i.e. The data is always comming from another program then bad input menas there is an error in another program. If there is user inputting the data you have to expect errors and it is not exceptional to have errors and you simply need to check the stream for error state and get the user to reinput the value in the correct range.

Answer (score 3):

By default, iostreams don't throw exceptions at all. You can handle invalid inputs by checking the state of the input stream. Here is fixed version that won't crash:

```
short a;
if(std::cin >> a) {
    std::cout << a;
} else {
    std::cout << "won't fit, or not a number";
}
```

See Quentin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69045109/2079303) for how to enable iostream exceptions if you prefer to use them.

Comment: But in my actual program, I am not asking the user to input a value, I myself is passing a value as a parameter to a function. Now, I know I will be not that stupid that I will trigger an exception myself by passing the limit, but just in case, you know, just in case. Also I am doing that program for my practice so yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Good thinking. [@eeorika's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69045034/3233393) shows you how to query an I/O stream to know after the fact that parsing has failed.

You can also enable exceptions on a stream by using its [`exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) member function:

```cpp
std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::failbit);
short s;
// Will throw an exception of type `std::ios_base::failure` if the number does not fit
std::cin >> s;
```